# How to break a do while loop?

Tags: c#, authentication, text-files

I am new to coding and have been trying to make a login using textfiles (i know i know its not secure its for practice with text files)

```
namespace text_file_login
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter user_reg =
                new StreamWriter(@"E:\SSD\Controled Assesment\text file login\text file login\username.txt");
            StreamWriter pass_reg =
                new StreamWriter(@"E:\SSD\Controled Assesment\text file login\text file login\password.txt");

            user_reg.WriteLine(txt_user.Text);
            user_reg.Close();
            pass_reg.WriteLine(txt_pass.Text);
            pass_reg.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Register was sucessful");
        }

        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string user = "";
            string pass = "";
            int user_line_number = 0;
            int pass_line_number = 0;
            StreamReader user_login =
                new StreamReader(@"E:\SSD\Controled Assesment\text file login\text file login\username.txt");
            StreamReader pass_login =
                new StreamReader(@"E:\SSD\Controled Assesment\text file login\text file login\password.txt");
            do
            {
                user = user_login.ReadLine();
                user_line_number++;
                if (user == txt_user.Text)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        pass = pass_login.ReadLine();
                        pass_line_number++;
                        if ((pass == txt_pass.Text) && (user_line_number == pass_line_number))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Login was succesful");
                            //this.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ((user_line_number > pass_line_number) || (user_line_number < pass_line_number))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password");
                            }
                        }
                    } while (pass_login.Peek() != -1);
                }
            } while (user_login.Peek() != -1);
        }
    }
}
```

The login works and the register works. However if the username or password is wrong im pretty sure this loops forever. How do i end the loops so that if the username or password is wrong i can show a messagebox?
im not too fused about multiple usernames however if you could is there anyway to fix this?

Sorry if this is poorly written. I am a beginner

Comment: Here you go: http://bit.ly/1w66zgY

Comment: yeah i realized that after i posted it just use an if statement for when read to end {break;} but i kept the question up so that if anyone reads the multiple username part and could help me with that

Comment: @JhWOLFJf If you still have a multi-user-something-or-another question and cannot solve it after some thought, feel free to post a new question

Comment: @VP. Thanks i was going to delete this and do so, but someone answered right away so i couldn't delete it. Feel stupid forgetting that to break you just break;. Sorry Coding all day and dealing with corrupted files has worn me down

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to "break" out of a loop, you literally do just that:

```
do {
    if (something)
        break;
}
while (condition)
```